# Data from mysql to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, mysql-python

I am trying to move the data from mysql to google bigquery. We need this as we are planning to create reports using google bigquery. I tried using a python code but it was throwing error with ray

Comment: Is your data stored in cloud sql?

Comment: No its a on premise mysql

Comment: The easy method is to extract the mysql database to ndjson and then import that file into BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks , yeah i tried that using mysqldump .. I was able to import it . But one more thing is this is not one time process . We want to move the data from mysql to google bigquery in schedule say every 1 hr  each day. MySQL is the db of our web application . We are moving it to Google big query so that we can integrate it with other data sources and build reports